# Show current location in map ios with CLLocationmanager

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location

I am trying to show current location in map but fails . It gives error as location is null . Which option should be selected in simulator debug location options . If i tries to use none than it returns null location nd for custom it gives location of pre decided coordinate . i wanna get current location !

Comment: Have you check that "Location services" is enable for your app or not? You can check it from: Device Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> Check permission for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get current location through simulator. All that you can do is give your current location's latitude and longitude in Debug -> Location -> Custom Location. This will be used as current location by your simulator.
Other option is to add GPX file to your project scheme.Edit Scheme -> Options -> Check Allow Location Simulation. Add GPX file to your project.[image: Adding GPX File]

Above settings are for debugging in simulator.It runs based on current location in real device even though these settings are not done(For faultless code).

Comment: @KiruthikaSelvavainayagan you r right i think his working on device.

Comment: but its not a proper way  by giving lat long in custom setting. It will show that location every other place . its static to that lat long only

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA : He is running his build in simulator

Comment: I don't think he have problem with his code. He have mentioned for custom location, he is getting predecided coordinate. He is asking about how to check current location in simulator. @JigarThakkar : Simulator can't find your current location like device do with GPS. So we can only use custom location settings which will be identified as simulator's current location.

Comment: so what to do when my app want to get current location ?

Comment: @JigarThakkar: You have two option.
1) Edit your custom location settings.
2) add gpx file to your scheme. Edit Scheme -> Options ->Check Allow Location Simulation. Add your gpx file which contains location.
Your code will run based on current location in real device. Above options are only for simulator.

Answer (score 0):

create object first

```
 CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 locationManager.delegate = self;

#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
 if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
 {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
 }
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

//Below two lines give you current location (lat-long).
Latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
NSLog(@"Lat====%@",Latitude);

Longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
NSLog(@"Log====%@",Longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this in `AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)  CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

You can use this for fetch current location. you can add this code in `AppDelegate.m` file

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        if (!_locationManager) {
            _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            _locationManager.delegate = self;
            _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
            _locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0;
            [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        }
        // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
        if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
            [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

Comment: in appdelegate or viewdidload ?

Comment: I am getting zero. What option should i select in debug option (simulator location option )?

Comment: you can change In simulator Debug>Location>Custom Location   change your cordinate

Comment: but with that custom coordinate i will get location with that coordinate only ! right ? i don't want to use pre decided coordinate

Comment: In simulator can not found current location.you can test in device at that time you can fetch current location.